# Gnome extension says to change Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler. What is this, and how do I change it

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, gnome-shell, workspace-switcher

After Ubuntu switched to Gnome, I installed the `workspace-grid` Gnome extension to have a grid of workspaces like in Unity. While I can switch left and right using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd>/<kbd>right</kbd> arrow key, moving up and down is more tricky. I need to use <kbd>function</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> key. It's jarring having to switch keys for the same action. Also, in some applications like Chrome, pressing <kbd>function</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> key scrolls down instead of changing workspace. I would like to change the up/down shortcut to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> arrow key.

Looking at [the github repo](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid) for the extension, it says:

> Workspaces can be changed by the user by a number of ways, and the ways this extension overrides are:
>
> - keybindings (Main.wm.setKeybindingHandler (GNOME 3.2), Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler (GNOME 3.4))

So what is `Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler` and how do I go about setting it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Gnome extension keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007928/how-to-change-gnome-extension-keyboard-shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

`Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler` refers to the gnome3 sourcecode - this is not a "setting" in the normal sense.

It is a function in the gnome-shell sourcecode in javascript, [see here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler&group_id=&project_id=546&search_code=true&repository_ref=master)

```
  setCustomKeybindingHandler: function(name, modes, handler) {
        if (Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler(name, handler))
            this.allowKeybinding(name, modes);
    },
```

or in use, [at this custom extension](http://kjo.herbesfolles.org/my_gnome_shell.html)

```
function enable() {
    Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler('switch-group', _doSwitchDesktop);
    Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler('switch-group-backward', _doSwitchDesktop);
}

function disable() {
    Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler('switch-group', Lang.bind(Main.wm, Main.wm._startAppSwitcher));
    Meta.keybindings_set_custom_handler('switch-group-backward', Lang.bind(Main.wm, Main.wm._startAppSwitcher));
}
```

If you write your own extension or rewrite an existing one, you can "*set*" it - if you will.

Comment: *I've reposted this answer from the duplicate question*